# How do I set animation to div behind image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a jsfiddle animation that I want to set to use as a background div of a png image. I can set the height and width of the animation and I tried setting it to the div using

```
document.getElementByID('progress').appendChild(canvas);
```

However, instead of the canvas displaying where it should it shows up under the image with the functioning animation. Here is [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jew651Lo/).

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/jew651Lo/1/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canvas will be placed underneath the #progressbar because the default css of this element is. `position:static;`.

When applying `position:absolute;` on the canvas it will be place on top of the #progressbar.

To be more precise:

```
#progress{
    position: relative;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Depending on the exact placement in the z-dimension, you can use `z-index:-1;` or `z-index:1;`. By doing this the canvas will be in front or behind the #progressbar.

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/u4cLxjrg/1/

Comment: one more question, if you navigate to the jsFiddle, shrink the window then expand it again the animation becomes more frequent and the rockets launch and explode in the space provided. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3qc2p1va/

I added some CSS styles to the canvas element, made it absolute and positioned relatively to its parent.

```
canvas {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css. Z-index will put the canvas under others div.

```
#progress {
        position: relative;
}

canvas {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
 }
```